# Using while loops to count elements in a list

Tags: python, while-loop

```
places = ["Jack", "John", "Sochi"]
count=0
multi_word=0
place  = places[count]
while place != "Sochi" and count < len(places):
    if ' ' in place:
        multi_word += 1

    count += 1
    place = places[count]

print ('Number of cities before Sochi:', count)
```

My code should print the number of cities before Sochi excluding Sochi  .  I don't understand what this line (place = places[count]) does, nor do I understand why I need it twice.

Comment: what is the line `**place  = places[count]**`?

Comment: @MrE it is the _bolded_ line which is not displayed bold because it is formatted as source code. ...and by the way it is initializing the variable `place` before used in the while loop.

Comment: Why not just `places.index('Sochi')` which will return the index for the string 'Sochi' in the list and since lists are zero-indexed you'll  get the sought after number

Answer (score 2):

foreach would neaten it up

```
places = ["Jack", "John", "Sochi"]
count = 0
for place in places:
    if ' ' in place:
        multi_word += 1
    if place == "Sochi":
        break
    count += 1
```

Comment: This feels more Python, whilst a while loops feels more C/C++

Answer (score 1):

```
count=0
place = places[count]
```

Now `place` is always `places[0]`, i.e. Jack. Thus the while loop only terminates on the second condition, giving you the list length of 3.

`place = places[count]` should go in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following `while` loop to check for the number of places before Sochi:

```
places = ["Jack", "John", "Sochi"]
count = 0
multi_word = 0
while count < len(places):
    place = places[count]
    if ' ' in place:
        multi_word += 1
    if place == "Sochi":
        break
    count += 1

print('Number of cities before Sochi:', count)
```

The [`break`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#break) statement means you'll exit your `while` loop.

Comment: I'd keep the `count < len(places)` condition. If "Sochi" is not in the list, you'll get out of bounds after the end.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try a more pythonic solution instead ?

```
places = ["Jack", "John", "Sochi"]

try:
    count = places.index("Sochi")
except ValueError:
    count = len(places)

multi_word = len([place for place in places[:count] if ' ' in place])
```