# What does [i] do after a variable name?

Tags: python

I've been following some Python tutorials and need some help with something.
In `htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(urls[i])` in the code below, I couldn't understand why `[i]` is needed after after the `urls`.

```
import urllib

urls = ["http://google.com","http://nytimes.com","http://cnn.com"]
i=0

while i< len(urls):
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(urls[i])
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    print htmltext
    i+=1
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19359093/using-while-loops-to-count-elements-in-a-list

Comment: That's not really very idiomatic Python.

Comment: @DanielRoseman And most answers say that quite clearly :P Use a `for` loop! :D

Answer (score 3):

`i` is indexing the list `urls`, allowing you to return the items one by one.  See below:

```
>>> urls = ["http://google.com","http://nytimes.com","http://cnn.com"]
>>> i = 0
>>> while i < len(urls):
...     print i, urls[i]
...     i += 1
...
0 http://google.com
1 http://nytimes.com
2 http://cnn.com
>>>
```

Also, I would like to mention that your code can be refactored to be more efficient:

```
import urllib
urls = ["http://google.com","http://nytimes.com","http://cnn.com"]
for url in urls:
    print urllib.urlopen(url).read()
```

This new code does exactly what the old one does.

Answer (score 2):

`urls` is a list of strings. The `[i]` refers to the `i`th element in that list, so you visit each site one at a time.

It's very much worth noting, though, that this is *not* a good, Pythonic way to iterate through a list. Your loop would be better and clearer like this:

```
for url in urls:
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    print htmltext
```

Also worth consideration: once you get more used to the code itself, you can do everything in that loop all at once, without assigning all those extra variables.

```
for url in urls:
    print urllib.urlopen(url).read()
```

Answer (score 1):

urls it's a list.
The [i] it's to choose between an item of that list.

For example, if:

```
>>> urls = ["http://google.com","http://nytimes.com","http://cnn.com"]
```

Then:

```
>>> urls[0]
"http://google.com"
>>> urls[1]
"http://nytimes.com"
```

And so on.

But, in your case, i would use a for loop instead a while, so you don't need to declare the loop variable before. Like this:

```
import urllib

urls = ["http://google.com","http://nytimes.com","http://cnn.com"]


for i in  range(len(urls)):
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(urls[i])
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    print htmltext
```

Answer (score 1):

This should really be rewritten. You have a list, not a tuple, so the position of items in the collection has no meaning.

```
import urllib

urls = ["http://google.com","http://nytimes.com","http://cnn.com"]

for url in urls:
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    print htmltext
```

It's also not very idiomatic to use a counter in Python if your iterating through all the items. Use it only when you need custom sequencing and then again there is the [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) package.

Comment: "you have a list, not a tuple, so the position of items in the collection has no meaning": huh?  You can index lists, just like tuples.  *sets* have no orders.

Comment: @DSM Exactly, tuples can be indexed as well.

Comment: No need to downvote guys, it's a matter of semantics. The position of any in `[foo, bar, baz, quux]` has no meaning, whereas in `(x,y,z)` or `(top, left, width, height)` it does, hence why tuples are also _immutable_. Comparatively, sets and lists also don't care about ordering, but sets add the additional semantics of representing a _unique_ collection of unordered items, which, again, might be undesirable for the context of the OP's requirements.

Answer (score 1):

`urls` is a list, and thus has an index. In order you access the values in a list, you must do so via its index. Let me demonstrate:

```
>>> urls = ['hello', 'world']
>>> urls[0]
'hello'
>>> urls[1]
'world'
>>> len(urls)
2
>>>
```

Please note that the index is `0` based (meaning the first element is a accessed via `0`, and then `1` is the second element). This is why the condition in your `while` statement reads `while i < len(url)`, because `i` is accessing the index, and since the index starts at `0` and not `1`, you can only continue it till `1` which is the second value in the list.

Let me demonstrate what happens if you go out of bounds by placing `2` in the index value:

```
>>> urls[2]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    urls[2]
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>
```

As you can see, you get an `IndexError`.

However, there is a better way to loop through the `list` of urls, in your case, using a `for` loop:

```
# This look will go through all the values inside your list, and the current value will be called url
for url in urls:  # Here url is the value inside the list
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    print htmltext
```

A demonstration using the `for` loop:

```
>>> for url in urls:
    print url


hello
world
>>>
```

Might I also suggest that you use [`python-requests`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests/2.0.0), it is excellent for sending requests, via common HTTP protocols such as `GET` and `POST`. It will save you a lot of [hassle in the future](https://gist.github.com/kennethreitz/973705).

Answer (score 0):

urls is a list so `url[i]` is needed to index the items in the list. Without the index you are trying to open a list of urls rather than a single url.

The while loop starts at `i=0` and iterates until `i < len(urls)` which is once for each item in `urls`.